# how to add image using in project which is loading image using LoadResPicture in VB6

Tags: vb6, bmp

I have a project which is loading images using:

```
imgwrc1.Picture = LoadResPicture(115, 0)
```

Now how do i add my image and give it id 116, 0 in the argument shows that it is a bitmap but there are no bitmaps in the project folder. So from where is the image being loaded.
I want to display this image in dialog

Comment: i know that the picture must be stored in a resource file, now how do i add my image to resource file in vb editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from addin manager got to load the VB Resource editor add in then, add the image to the resource file then acccess it using LoadResPicture function.